# How to convert a dropdownlist (select) to a textbox using plain javascript or jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, drop-down-menu, textbox

I have an ASP.Net page that is coded to populate a bunch of textboxes and dropdowns on page load, and then depending on the selected values of the dropdowns on selected index changed events fire to show/hide other elements on the page.

I want to keep all that logic, such that the page loads with all the correct fields shown, and all the data is populated. In addition though, once the page has finished loading (and all the elements have hidden/shown that need to, i.e. my code has run) I want to convert all the dropdowns into textboxes, setting the text of the textboxes to the selected value (if one was set, or blank if no value was selected/populated on page load).

I accomplish this by simply adding a hidden textbox next to each dropdownlist control, and then manually setting the textbox to the dropdownlist selected value in code behind, then hiding the ddl, and showing the textbox, but I get the feeling there is some quick and easy way to do this with jQuery. I am new to jQuery and am hoping somebody here can point me in the right direction.

Ideally the solution would allow me to loop through and do this for all dropdownlist/select elements on the page but not necessary (I can apply it individually as there arent that many lists).

Comment: please explain the close vote. this is not a duplicate I have already checked. otherwise please link and explain how its a dup.

Comment: You have multiple close votes because your question isn't very clear and you have provided zero code or logic that you have tried.  I's suggest you try to be more succinct.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use the replaceWith function: http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/

$('#YourDdlId').replaceWith(
 $('').attr({
    name: 'whatever',
    value: $("#YourDdlId' option:selected").text()
 })

Comment: +1 for trying to answer. thanks, i ended up just replacing the dropdownlist with textboxes though. I made the mistake of thinking the on selected index events fired on page load (when the values were populated and a selected index was set). Since it wasnt I was able to keep all the same logic and just switch out the DDLs for Textboxes.